# Trego Wordpress theme

Tags: wordpress

could anyone please help me with Trego theme? I'm sorry if i ask damn questions, but i'm new to wp.
I'm supposed to write something like this:
http://newsmartwave.net/preview.html?trego_wp

I have a theme itself, I just need to make it look like this.
But im not sure, 
for the home page, is it like a one page or there are several posts?
how did they make it?
and what plugin do they use for Portfolio section to make the photo bigger when a user clicks on it?

I would really appreciate any help!
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

About Trego Theme and recommend plugins you can view here - http://wordpressthemesamples.com/trego/

But if you are looking for information on the needed website, it is best to use a resource seomon.com